# How to use class ContentQueryMap to cache Cursor values?

Tags: android, caching, cursor

I read that ContentQueryMap can be used to access Cursor values not to access the db everytime.

But, how to use it?
The Official Android help is hermetic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       ContentQueryMap mQueryMap = new ContentQueryMap(cursor, BaseColumns._ID, true, null);

        Comparator<Long> numberAmaxB = new Comparator<Long>() {
            @Override public int compare(Long s1, Long s2) {
                if (s1<s2)
                    return 1;
                else if (s1>s2)
                    return -1;
                else
                    return 0;
            }           
        };
        SortedMap<Long, String> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, String>(numberAmaxB);

        for (Map.Entry<String, ContentValues> row : mQueryMap.getRows().entrySet()) {

            Long _ID = Long.valueOf(row.getKey());
            String data= row.getValue().getAsString("data_column");
         conversationsSortedMap.put(_ID, data);
        }
```

Comment: When You submit answer, should write comment about it. I can't understand your answer.

Comment: @omidnazifi I disagree. The code snippet in this case is sufficient since it clearly provides example stated by question

Comment: Dear @Bostone I disagree with you, too. because if a beginner programmer want to use this code, he/she can't. Question has not been adequately explained.

Comment: @omidnazifi I agree, yes... But if the beginner programmer is my grandmother. :-P